# Is it possible to edit the tag description of a synonymous tag?

Tags: support, tags, suggested-edits, tag-synonym-process

This is regarding the [cocos2d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cocos2d) tag which is a synonym for the [cocos2d-iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cocos2d-iphone) tag.

Unfortunately many users type in "cocos2d" in their questions which expands to [cocos2d-iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cocos2d-iphone) even though their question has nothing to do with that specific version of cocos2d.

Here's the original [cocos2d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cocos2d) tag description a user sees when entering the tag:

[image]

However when I try to edit this tag it only shows the [cocos2d-iphone] description and clicking edit starts editing the description of [cocos2d-iphone].

[image]

I wanted to modify the [cocos2d] description so that it reads like the [cocos2d-iphone] tag description or maybe even just saying "DO NOT USE THIS TAG" (though I'm sure SO has developed better solutions for such cases).

Is it possible to edit the original [cocos2d] tag's description?

If not what else can/should be done about the confusing fact that people type [cocos2d] and hence add [cocos2d-iphone] tags even to unrelated questions concerning cocos2d-android, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-html5, and so on?

I'm all in favor of simply removing the [cocos2d] tag altogether (merge it into [cocos2d-iphone]) because there are very little overarching, unifying "cocos2d" elements and as is all questions relating multiple versions of the engine (or a common element) are being tagged with multiple cocos2d tags anyway. I've also retagged the few [cocos2d] (originally referring to [cocos2d-python]) tags in the past anyway, so there's no need in keeping the [cocos2d] tag come to think of it.

Comment: Does this work for you? http://stackoverflow.com/edit-tag-wiki/17664

Comment: Why is `cocos2d` a synonym for `cocos2d-iphone`?  If many users are typing `cocos2d` and not meaning `cocos2d-iphone`, then it should not be synonymous.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you hit a bug but we have to  wait for confirmation.

Until then you could use the following workaround:

Enter the following url directly in the addressbar of your browser:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/tags/cocos2d/info
```

and hit the edit tag wiki button.